# Rotar un objeto con el movimiento de la cabeza en Unity para una app de Google CardBoard

Tags: unity3d, unity

He hecho una aplicación sencilla en unity para las Google CardBoard. La escena se compone de un objeto en el centro y la cámara principal de la escena. He introducido todos los prefabs del SDK de Google CardBoard. Mi problema es que me gustaría que el objeto hiciera los movimientos de la cabeza y la cámara se estuviera quieta. Hay una app en la tienda llamada "CardBoard" que tiene exáctamente el funcionamiento que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El SDK de Google tiene un prefab llamado GVREditorEmulator, su función es simular el movimiento de la cabeza, mi duda es como conseguir orbitar alreadedor del objeto, tengo dos ideas. 1) Que el movimiento de la cámara lo haga el objeto. 2) que la cámara orbite alrededor del objeto.

Yo he intentado cambiar el movimiento de la cámara por el de mi objeto en el Script, pero cuando ejecuto la app el objeto no se mueve ni rota:

```
public void UpdateEditorEmulation(){

  HeadRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, mouseZ);
  HeadPosition = HeadRotation * NECK_OFFSET - NECK_OFFSET.y * Vector3.up;

  IEnumerator<Camera> validCameras = ValidCameras();
  while (validCameras.MoveNext()) {
  Camera cam = validCameras.Current;
  /* Esta línea movía la cámara */
  //cam.transform.localPosition = HeadPosition * cam.transform.lossyScale.y;

  MiObjeto.transform.localPosition = HeadPosition * cam.transform.lossyScale.y;

  /* Esta línea rotaba la cámara */
  //cam.transform.localRotation = HeadRotation;

  MiObjeto.transform.localRotation = HeadRotation;
}
```

¿Algúna ayuda de que API mirar, información, etc? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, es la primera vez que escribo en un foro.

Comment: Aquí hay un asset que te puede ayudar. [https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/cardboard-controls-25243](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/cardboard-controls-25243) Saludos.